# MERN stack regex filter with search box and checkbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to learn how MERN stack is working together by learning by doing and I am following these tutorials from bezcoder: [Node.js/Express/MongoDb](https://www.bezkoder.com/node-express-mongodb-crud-rest-api/) ([Github entire code](https://github.com/bezkoder/node-express-mongodb)) and [Reactjs](https://www.bezkoder.com/react-crud-web-api/) ([Github entire code](https://github.com/bezkoder/react-crud-web-api))

**Example data from server**

```
[
  {
    "id": "5f9bdace778082303c859248",
    "title": "How to cook noodles",
    "description": "This is a tutorial about how to cook noodles in under 10 minutes.",
    "published": false
  },
  {
    "id": "5f9bdae3778082303c859249",
    "title": "How to bake a chocolate cake",
    "description": "This is a tutorial about how to bake chocolate cake using cocoa powder.",
    "published": true
  }
]
```

**Current situation**
Currently, the front-end of the App has a search bar, where I can search and filter the data by the "title" of the tutorial (e. g. "noodles" in order to get the first one).
I found out that this is done by the following snippets:

1. tutorial.controller.js

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  const title = req.query.title;
  var condition = title ? { title: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" } } : {};

  Tutorial.find(condition)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
      });
    });
};
```

2. services/tutorial.service.js (in Reactjs)

```
import http from "../http-common";

class TutorialDataService {

...
  
  findByTitle(title) {
    return http.get(`/tutorials?title=${title}`);
  }
}

export default new TutorialDataService();
```

**What I would like to know is**, how can I change those codes so that I can filter by words from "title" and "description" from the search box, as well as published:true by a checkbox.

If the front end would look like this:
[image: front end search and checkbox]

**My attempts**

1. tutorial.controller.js

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  const title = req.query.title || "";
  const description = req.query.description || "";
  const published = req.query.published;

  Tutorial.find(
    {
    $or: [
        {title: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i"}}, {description: { $regex: new RegExp(description), $options: "i"}}
    ],
    $and: [
        .... and here if checked, then only show published, else show all ....
    ]

}

  )
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
      });
    });
};
```

2. services/tutorial.service.js (in Reactjs)

```
import http from "../http-common";

class TutorialDataService {

...
  
  findByTitle(title, description, published) {
    return http.get(`/tutorials?title=${title}`, `/tutorials?description=${description}`, `/tutorials?published=${published}`);
  }
}

export default new TutorialDataService();
```

I'm not sure if that's even the correct usage of `findByTitle` and how I have to implement OR and AND function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `{` mistake in tutorial find query. `$or` need separate `{ }` for every query. use like below. it will work. for search in title, description and published check box.

```
Tutorial.find:({
$or: [
        {title: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i"},
        {description: { $regex: new RegExp(description), $options: "i"}
    ],
published:true
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that part. Unfortunately, there is still something wrong in my code as I don't get a filtered result. I suspect that it is a problem on the React side, but I am not sure...